# Find the exact value of $\int^\infty_0\frac{5x^{2/3}}{-2-3x^{12/5}} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Find the exact value of $$\int^\infty_0\frac{5x^\frac{2}{3}}{-2-3x^\frac{12}{5}} dx$$

I've tried using integration by parts. If you make $U=x^{10/15}$ then you end up with a more complicated expression.

If you make $u=-2-3x^\frac{12}{5}$ then we end up with an expression that is of equal difficulty.

Subsequently I think neither of these directions are the way to go and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. If someone thinks that either of those $u$'s actually would work than I'd be happy to write the work I did.

If $U=x^\frac{1}{15} \text{ then }du=\frac{1}{15x^\frac{14}{15}}$ already this seems very unwieldy and I'm not sure how to fit in.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? I assume you are asking for the integral of this expression. Indefinite or definite?

Comment: The standard trick would be to substitute $u=x^{1/15}$, so that the resulting expression involved only integer powers of $u$. No idea how nasty it works out to be though.

Comment: @rogerl Definite

Comment: @GregMartin I'll give it a go.

Comment: If this is a definite integral, what are the limits of integration?

Comment: There's nothing intrinsically difficult about this integral, but actually writing out the full antiderivative seems masochistically tedious. How badly do you want an explicit solution?

Comment: @DavidH Quite badly, I'd appreciate if you you would solve even part of the way though.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? I asked Maple to do the integral and it came back with an answer taking about 3 screenfuls.

Comment: @BernardMassé I got similar results from mathematica.

Comment: The integral actually is a definite integral. I've added the bounds to the problem. I don't really see why knowing the bounds will help though.

Comment: @chriskinda *"I don't really see why knowing the bounds will help though."* Prepare for a lesson in definite integrals!

Comment: And there must be some sort of short cut, but nothing in the chapter seems to apply to this problem. I doubt the author (who is also my professor) would put a problem that took pages to write though; especially since this problem has 2 parts.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Factor $-\dfrac52$ forcefully outside of the integral sign, then let $t^\tfrac{12}5=\dfrac32~x^\tfrac{12}5$ and

$u=\dfrac1{1+t^\tfrac{12}5}~,~$ and recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral,

then use Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to simplify the expression.

Comment: The final result should be $-\dfrac{25}{12}\cdot\dfrac\pi{\sqrt[36]{2^{11}~3^{25}}} \cdot\csc\bigg(\dfrac{25}{36}~\pi\bigg)$.

Comment: The gamma function is not introduced for another 3 chapters. The beta function is also far far and I don't see anything about Euler's reflection formula. Is it possible there is an easier, albeit longer, solution?

Comment: @chriskinda: Sure. Just not a very elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

In math there are all sorts of powerful tools to evaluate definite integrals of this sort. You can use contour integration to tackle this integral.

First, we make the substitution $x=u^{15}$. This turns the integral to 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{75u^{24}}{-2-3u^{36}} du$$

Now we do complex analysis. Promote $u$ to a complex variable; we are now integrating over the half-real line in the complex plane. But we can do better: take a path $C$ in the complex plane: $C_1+C_2+C_3$. $C_1$ is the real line; the part we want for our solution. $C_2$ is a path at $r=\infty$, and $C_3$ is a radial path leading back to the origin; take it to be at an angle $\pi/18$. Then use Cauchy's Residue Theorem.

$$\oint_{C}\dfrac{75u^{24}}{-2-3u^{36}} du = 2\pi i Res(C)$$

I'll leave the rest to you.